# CPLEX+JAVA: Retrieving Solution inside Heuristic Callback behaves weirdly

Tags: java, cplex

I have the following problem: I solve a large VRP with many synchronization constraints using CPLEX integrated with a heuristic component to improve incumbents. The general algorithm is as follows: If a new incumbent is found in  CPLEX, or if a time limit is reached, I move to a heuristic, and try to improve the current incumbent. The former is done using an Incumbent Callback, the latter using a Heuristic Callback. While I am able to query all variables in the incumbent callback, I get some weird behavior in the heuristic callback: 
When I query

```
this.getStatus().toString()
```

this returns "Optimal", even though the solution is not optimal yet (there is an incumbent, but still a rather large integrality gap). I made sure that the model actually queries the correct cplex object by looking into objective value and current integrality gap, they match the log. Then,

```
this.getIncumbentValue(v[n][i][j]);
```

fails (it also fails if I query the values using `this.getIncumbentValues(v[n][i]);`).

When I check in the model (using `cplex.exportModel(String filename)`, all variables are present.

I was thinking that this might be related to the fact that I use CPLEX as a singleton, but the status is already "optimal" when I use the singleton for the first time (in the first iteration however, all variables can be queried, this problem only exists in the second iteration).

I create the singleton as such:

```
public static IloCplex getCplex() {
    if (cplex == null) {
        try {
            cplex = new IloCplex();
        } catch (IloException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            cplex.clearModel();
            cplex.setDefaults();
        } catch (IloException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return cplex;
}
```

Did I maybe do something wrong here?

EDIT: The exact error message including back trace is:

```
ilog.cplex.IloCplex$UnknownObjectException: CPLEX Error: object is unknown to IloCplex
 at ilog.cplex.CpxNumVar.getVarIndexValue(CpxNumVar.java:295)
 at ilog.cplex.IloCplex$MIPInfoCallback.getIndex(IloCplex.java:13648)
 at ilog.cplex.IloCplex$MIPInfoCallback.getIncumbentValues(IloCplex.java:13807)
 at ilog.cplex.IloCplex$MIPInfoCallback.getIncumbentValues(IloCplex.java:13785)
 at SolverHybridCRP$InsertSolution.getV(SolverHybridCRP.java:2091)
 at SolverHybridCRP$InsertSolution.improveIncumbent(SolverHybridCRP.java:2054)
 at SolverHybridCRP$InsertSolution.main(SolverHybridCRP.java:2024)
 at ilog.cplex.CpxCallback.callmain(CpxCallback.java:160)
 at ilog.cplex.CpxHeuristicCallbackFunction.callIt(CpxHeuristicCallbackFunction.java:48)
 at ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXmipopt(Native Method)
 at ilog.cplex.CplexI$SolveHandle.start(CplexI.java:2837)
 at ilog.cplex.CplexI.solve(CplexI.java:2963)
 at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.solve(IloCplex.java:10254)
 at SolverHybridCRP.solveModel(SolverHybridCRP.java:1525)
 at AppHelp.runtimeTest4(AppHelp.java:1218)
 at AppHelp.main(AppHelp.java:61)
```

it occurs when I query ANY variable, but only after I query the cplex object the second time. (So: I start the program, it iterates over a lot of instances, the first instance is fine, all heuristic callbacks work, in all further iterations, I end up in the catch-block and get the above exception trace.)
That is why I assumed that maybe the singleton does not work exactly as supposed, and not everything is deleted from the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [reference documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.HeuristicCallback.html#getStatus()) you can see for `IloCplex.HeuristicCallback.getStatus()`

> Returns the solution status for the current node.
>
> This method returns the status of the solution found by the instance
>   of IloCplex at the current node during the last call to the method
>   IloCplex.HeuristicCallback.solve (which may have been called directly
>   in the callback or by IloCplex when processing the node just before
>   the callback is called).

In other words, the function does not return a global status but only a node-local status. It is expected that the node is currently solved to optimality when the callback is invoked.

With respect to the exception in the callback: you are trying to access a variable object that is not in the model being solved. Typical cases in which this happens are:

1. You created the variable but it does not appear in any constraints or in the objective, i.e., it is not used anywhere. You can force its usage by explicitly calling `cplex.add()` with the variable as argument.
2. The variable was created in a previous iteration and is no longer part of the model in the current iteration. A good way to debug this is to assing a name to each variable and have that name include the iteration index. Then in the exception handler print the name of the offending variable. That should give a very good hint about what is wrong.

Comment: thanks Daniel. that explains the first half. I am just still surprised that I cannot query the values even though all variables exist in the model (only in the second iteration)

Is there a better way of implementing the singleton? (I am using it as Java cannot correctly remove models using the Garbage Collector).

Comment: What exactly is the problem when querying the variables? Can you extend your question with a detailed description of what goes wrong? Add a potential exception message and/or backtrace. In case the exception occurs inside a callback, try to wrap your callback into something like `try { /* callback code */ } catch (IloException e) { System.err.println(e); e.printStackTrace(e); throw e; }` since that gives more verbose exception reporting.

Comment: thanks Daniel. I edited the question above, giving the exception message. The error occurs from the second iteration onwards, that is all heuristic callbacks on the first set of instances work, but when I get the cplex object the second time (from the singleton), it fails.

Comment: I have updated my answer with potential explanations for the exceptions.

Comment: I tried both. The "correct" variables are offending, and I checked the model using exportModel(), and all variables are added. (Also, as ALL variables are offending and it starts solving the model, this would be rather surprising also).
I thought that the problem might be somehow related to the singleton, is there something "stronger" than clearModel and setDefaults that I could use? Something that really destroys the entire model and completely rebuilds it without any remaining fragments?

Comment: What happens if you temporarily abandon the singleton pattern and just have method `getCplex()` always allocate a new cplex instance? That would make sure you are not using any stale information. Also, can you share a minimal working example to reproduce your problem? Note that for this the injected heuristic solution need not be feasible. Since the exceptions is triggered when trying to inject the solution it is sufficient to inject just *any* solution.

Comment: if I do not use the Singleton pattern, I quickly run out of memory, since Java seems to have issues allocating the memory. Is there an alternative how to free up memory? Or a way to tell Java to discard the old cplex object and all that comes along with it?

Comment: Do you call `cplex.end()`? This is required to release the native resources allocated by the `IloCplex` instance.

Comment: Using cplex.end() and System.gc() slows down the memory excess, but does not stop it entirely. However, I found a way to circumvent the problem, I simply call the instances manually. I do not investigate too many instances, so this should work for me. Thanks for all your help!